# iPhone/iPad change pitch/tempo in realtime

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I am developing an app for the iPhone/iPad using Xcode and iOS 5. Can anyone suggest any third  party libs to do this, or give me some direction as to how to natively do it?

Comment: Not an XCode question. XCode tags is for specific questions about the IDE.

Comment: Hahaha! Ok, will remember for next time. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bass` and `Bass_fx` library for changing pitch/tempo in real time.

You can download this library from http://www.un4seen.com/.

You can use following function for Pitch and tempo setting

> BASS_ChannelSlideAttribute(mainStream, BASS_ATTRIB_TEMPO_PITCH, 0.0,
>   updatePeriod);

which is available in `Bass` library.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this sdk http://www.izotope.com/tech/iZomobile/
it uses audioqueue bit complicated yet powerfull